# GridView for Android?

Tags: android

I am using GridView in my Android application. [image: This is what it looks like in eclipse]

As you can see, I am using it for a 'mini' calendar.

This is my code to 'update the calendar' and put the information into the grid.

```
items.add(name + "\n" + time + "\n" + amount);  
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, is there a way I can specify to the GridView where I want to put this item? Is there a method to do this? For example, if the tab that is highlighted is Sunday and a new medication is added, I want it to go under Sunday always.

As of now, it travels to the right (so, when I keep adding in medications, it goes under Sunday first, then Monday, then Tuesday, etc.)

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Do you specifically require a `GridView` or you could use other options?

Comment: I could use other options. Is it not possible to do this in GridView?

Comment: By using a `GridView` and an `Adapter` you'll have to work hard to get the `Adapter` data to show as you want. For example, in your image, if you want to insert a element on `sunday` will have to fill the adapter with empty elements(and take care to fill them if you later add data in those places). You could use a `TableLayout` instead and use 7 `ArrayList` that will hold the data for each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've come a long way with your `GridView` so far, but I figured I should point out that there are other options.

1. For >= API 11+, check out [`CalenderView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) (from the Android public SDK).
2. For < API 11, there are a few open source libraries you could use. I've heard good things about [`Android-Calender-View`](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/) and [`CalenderView`](http://caughtinthemobileweb.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/how-to-implement-calendarview-in-android/) (both third-party libraries).

Comment: Alex Lockwood, well actually I should only have to change a few things. I will check out both and get back to you.

Comment: It was only a suggestion... it looks like you are writing your application for tablets so `CalenderView` is most likely the easiest option in your case. Supporting handheld devices might be a bit tricker though...

Comment: I agree. For now, I am supporting the Blackberry Playbook only, but I understand what you are saying.